# touch is creating files one hour behind the current time. How to set it with current time?

Tags: centos, nfs, timestamps, timezone, touch

All ordinary users on my linux box have an issue. When they create a file using `$ touch test.txt` or using script and do `ls -ali | grep test.txt` I notice that the time of the file is one hour behind current time.

I checked system time using `$ date` command and it shows the current time. I also tried adding:

`TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London" export TZ`

Then logged out and logged in again but same issue. How to fix the issue so that the new files are created with the current time?

I have `CentOS release 6.6`

```
$ rm -f test; touch test; date -r test; date;echo test>>test; date -r test
Wed Nov 15 10:02:41 GMT 2017
Wed Nov 15 11:00:25 GMT 2017
Wed Nov 15 10:02:41 GMT 2017
```

Filesystem over NFS.  I checked the time of my storage from settings and it was right.

Comment: Check if there is an alias for touch with "alias touch"

Comment: If you create a new file using something like `vi` do you see the same issue?

Comment: What's the output of `rm -f test.txt; touch test.txt; date -r test.txt; date; echo test >> test.txt; date -r test.txt`? What's the file system? local or NFS/CIFS?

Comment: `Wed Nov 15 10:02:41 GMT 2017
Wed Nov 15 11:00:25 GMT 2017
Wed Nov 15 10:02:41 GMT 2017`

Comment: NFS. I checked the time of my storage from settings and it was right

Comment: What about after `touch -d "2017-11-15 10:00:00" test; date -r test`? (please add the info to your question)

Comment: If I create a file using vi, it is also created with timestamp 1 hour behind.

Comment: output is `Wed Nov 15 10:00:00 GMT 2017`

Comment: Most likely, timezone is not properly configured on the NFS server here (and the clock is also off a few seconds). Consider synchronising the clocks of all your servers with NTP.

Comment: Return to standard time from daylight saving time didn't happen? (If any of this is in a zone that honors such.)

Comment: x-site dup: [Why are the timestamps on files created on an NFS mounted partition different?](//superuser.com/q/653296)

Comment: The problem is with the primary storage but strange one. I tried to set the time manually to the current time on primary storage and the `touch file` was one hour behind so I set the manual time one hour forward. After that the `touch file` was created on the current time.

Comment: I tried to set ntp to london `0.uk.pool.ntp.org` but that didnt work